# jQuery - how to prevent click event on merged classes to also be interpreted as click event on a single class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I listen for 2 click events. First one fires when checkbox is checked:

```
        $('#example').on('click', '.option', function(){
        // Some logic
    });
```

Second one fires when it's unchecked:

```
            $('#example').on('click', '.checked.option', function(){
        // Some other logic
    });
```

As for HTML input element, I tried applying class to it in various ways:

```
class="checked option"
class="checked.option"
class="option checked"
class="option.checked"
```

But in either case, when checkbox is unchecked - both events get triggered instead of just second one.

QUESTION: Is there a way to prevent this? Or is there a more convenient way to detect click event on a checkbox AND that it was unchecked?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you adding checkboxes to the DOM or is there another reason you're using event delegation? While the solutions below will solve your issue, I'd suggest binding directly to the inputs if delegation is unneeded.

Comment: Yes, they are dynamically added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really use the `change` event instead of a `click` and then check the button state.

```
 $('#example').on('change', '.option', function() {
     if( this.checked ) {
     }
     else {
     }
 });
```

Comment: did I miss anything here? please give the world and me a headsup for the downvotes

Comment: Yes, I'd also be curious to know. I now have 3 working solutions, but this one is shortest and was the first - is there any downside to it?

Comment: @Freelancer: no, not at all. But these times there are pretty ignorant and stupid wannabes around this site it seems.

Comment: +1 @jAndy - But I would update if event delegation isn't needed (see my comment on the original question).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways:

```
$('#example').on('click', '.option', function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) ...
});
```

See the `checked` selector http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Or:

```
$('#example').on('click', '.option:not(.checked)', function(){
    ...
});
```

See the `not` selector http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Or even:

```
$('#example').on('click', '.option:not(:checked)', function(){
    ...
});

$('#example').on('click', '.option:checked', function(){
    ...
});
```

Oh, and BTW, classes should be applied like: `class="option checked"`, you should never put a `.` in the class attribute.

Comment: just access `this.checked` please.

Comment: because its insane overkill to invoke the jQuery constructor +  an additional function + a slow pseudo selector

Comment: @jAndy unless you clicking at a rate of 5000 clicks per second, I don't think it matters. `premature optimization is the root of all evil`

Comment: thats not premature optimization. Its just using the common sense.

Answer (score 1):

> QUESTION: Is there a way to prevent this? Or is there a more convenient way to detect click event on a checkbox AND that it was unchecked?

Yes, the code below should prevent it and I would use jQuery selectors (convenient imo) to detect this. 
Hope this helps! Thanks.

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert('was un-checked');               
    } else {
        alert('was checked');
    }
});
```

**​​See the code work here:**

http://jsfiddle.net/SCSZ6/